# How to connect to a different team project collection with tfs power tools in windows shell?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs-power-tools

We are migrating from TFS 2010 to TFS 2012. Some of the members don't have visual studio installed and won't be using but still need to be able to connect to TFS, hence we are using power tools. My question the people who are not using visual studio how will they be able to change the team project collection from the windows shell? Is this even possible?

Appreciate any help you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just select, delete or modify Workitems, i suggest you to install `Team Explorer`, this product setup on your `Excel Addin` , permit to access your datas `without Visual Studio`, when you connect you can select easily  `your project collection` 
Command line is not fluent to select or modify data.

Note : Before you install check your Excel, and section Addin Team Foundation